# input element isn't working for the pattern I'm trying to use

Tags: html, angular

On my html page I have:

```
......
<div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="manufacturer.name" [value]="manufacturer.name" maxlength="30" name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel" pattern="[\x20-\x7E]" required />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <validation-message [control]="name" [message]="'Manufacturer Name must be an alphanumeric value of no more than 30 characters'"></validation-message>
          </div>
......
```

Where I'm trying to restrict input to Ascii 32 to 126 inclusive. However, my Pattern doesn't seem to work. I cannot see what is wrong with it. Basically my validation message stays constantly on screen. How should I write my pattern?

Comment: Are u using any library?

Comment: No, but I think I've just solved it. On the end of my pattern I needed to add `+` so that it becomes `[\x20-\x7E]+`

Comment: Right, as this is regex, u need to specify that one or more occurrences are required by +.